# Xamarin Forms and Prism Navigation history

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

I'm developing a Xamarin.Forms application with Prism framework in a MVVM architecture.
In each page I do the navigation with the INavigationService object like this:

```
_navigationService.NavigateAsync("PageB");
```

In the bottom-left side of the application I have the back button with I can go back in the pages.

I have a navigation like this:

MainPage -> PageA -> PageB -> PageC -> PageD

When I'm in PageD, I need a button that jumps to PageA, but I need to preserve part of my navigation history, like this:

MainPage -> PageA

How I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem with this code:

```
_navigationService.NavigateAsync("/NavigationPage/MainPage/PageA", null,false,false);
```

I hope it can be useful for someone.

Comment: Could you tell me how your initial navigation looks like? I am facing the very same issue, but I'm still getting the *"Cannot destroy NavigationPage"* exception. Initially I am navigation to my start page with `this.NavigationService.NavigateAsync("/NavigationRootPage/DevicesPage");` and at a later point in time I am trying to return to my settings page with `await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("/NavigationRootPage/DevicesPage/SettingsPage", null, false);` - still the same exception.

Comment: Okay, got it. Using `await` was wrong here. Since your answer is the accepted answer, could you maybe add the information, that awaiting the call to `NavigateAsync` will result in the mentioned exception?

Comment: Arent you doing a Absolute redirect there? you are recreating your whole nav stacl

Answer (score 1):

Use *relative* navigation.
If you know you're three pages ahead, you can simply navigate relatively to your target page.

```
// using 3x '..'
_navigationService.NavigateAsync("../../..");

/* 

Current stack: MainPage -> PageA -> PageB -> PageC -> PageD

..          -> MainPage -> PageA -> PageB -> PageC
../..       -> MainPage -> PageA -> PageB
../../..    -> MainPage -> PageA  

*/
```

You could also navigate four times back and then navigate to a different page creating following nav stack (basically replacing PageA):

```
_navigationService.NavigateAsync("../../../../AnotherPage"); // -> MainPage/AnotherPage
```

Answer (score 0):

The NavigationService can only handle Popping a single View off the NavigationStack at a time. This leaves you with two options for your scenario:

1. `_navigationService.NavigateAsync("/MainPage/PageA")` this will bring you back to the view you want but would be recreating the MainPage and PageA.
2. Probably the better option is to use the NavigationParameters along with `INavigatedAware`. To do this your Go Back command may do something like

   _navigationService.GoBackAsync(new NavigationParameters
   {
       { "goBackTo" : "PageA" }
   });

You could then update your ViewModels to do something like this:

```
public class PageBViewModel : BindableBase, INavigationAware
{
    public const string Key = "PageB";

    public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        switch(parameters.GetNavigationMode())
        {
            case NavigationMode.Back:
                var goBackTo == parameters.GetValue<string>("goBackTo");
                if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(goBackTo) && goBackTo != Key)
                {
                    _navigationService.GoBackAsync(parameters);
                    return;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried with the first solution but I receive this exception: "Cannot destroy Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage."

Comment: You'd need to provide a sample that demonstrates the issue... If you're doing what I showed as option 1, then you're resetting the `Application.MainPage`

Comment: I tried also the second solution but it doesn't work. In the first page (for example PageC the parameter "goBackTo" exists in the parameters, in the next page (PageB) the parameter is not present while I put it again in the parameters. I tried also to create a new NavigationParameters object and put in it the parameter, but in the second jump I lose it. It's very strange.

Comment: Without a sample duplicating the problem it’s hard to say what is going on. Either of the examples I gave should work.

Comment: Update: I tried to check the parameters in the second landing page (PageB). In OnNavigatingTo method the variable exists, in OnNavigatedTo method it doesn't exist. Seems that it loose the value between these 2 steps.

Comment: Unfortunatly I can't share the company code. I tried with: _navigationService.NavigateAsync("MainPage/PageA"); and it works, but I lose the navigationbar in the top of the page. How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: Wouldn’t expect that you would share company code. Just a simple reproduction. As you have said you tried the first example and had an exception the best thing to do is to create a sample that would allow to replicate the errors you’re seeing.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for your help. I solved the issue. I wrote the answer, you can read it above. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform an absolute navigation. 
This is done by prefixing your uri with a "/".

```
_navigationService.NavigateAsync("/MainPage/PageA")
```

This will reset your App.MainPage

**=======================UPDATED=========================**

You need to register your all page in Container. 
So, Please make sure with your App file code with below my code:

```
public partial class App : PrismApplication
{
    public App(IPlatformInitializer initializer = null) : base(initializer) { }
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NavigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/MainPage");
    }
    protected override void RegisterTypes()
    {
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<MainPage>();
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<PageA>();
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<PageB>();
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<PageC>();
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<PageD>();
        Container.RegisterType<ITsApiService, TsApiService>();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried but I receive this exception: "Cannot destroy Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage."

Comment: I have update my answer with code _navigationService.NavigateAsync("/MainPage/PageA") Please try it and let me know

Comment: yes, I tried this code in the first time and I received the mentioned exception

Comment: @TeoVr81, I have updated my answer please have a look and let me know.

Comment: yes, all the pages are registered. I don't have the RegisterType, I don't know what are ITsApiService and TsApiService.

Comment: I tried to add a button in the second page. For example PageC if the navigation is: MainPage -> PageA -> PageB -> PageC -> PageD. In the PageB I receive the data when I click the button, the problem (I think) is the double jump, If I resend the data in the onNavigatedTo method of the PageC I will not receive the data in the PageB.

Comment: Update: I tried to check the parameters in the second landing page (PageB). In OnNavigatingTo method the variable exists, in OnNavigatedTo method it doesn't exist. Seems that it loose the value between these 2 steps.

Comment: Unfortunatly I can't share the company code. I tried with: _navigationService.NavigateAsync("MainPage/PageA"); and it works, but I lose the navigationbar in the top of the page. How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: Try  _navigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/MainPage/PageA"); it will solved your problem